what is the title of this cast away movie?
There's this movie I was kind of watching the other day but I fell asleep. It was about a couple, a man and a woman, that for some reason ended up living on some island and apparently they didn't get along well at first. I remember a scene where the man builds a system to carry water into the place they were living by creating a piping system using bamboos cut in half. 
I think the man has a beard, his hair was black, he was possibly in his forties, and that he used to fish.
I don't think it is a comedy, but rather more like a drama love story.  I think it was also sort of slow. The movie didn't seem new, probably from the middle 80's to the 90's, but I'm unsure.
It was either in English or Spanish. The reason I'm unsure of this is because they don't talk much and I only remember the man working and fishing.

difficult to find with only this information, several movie come to mind. Is it more like a drama, love story, or some kind of comedy? Do you remember how the protagonist looked like? Any Idea from which country it was?

@kl78 the man had a beard, his hair was black and was over his thirties, maybe forties. I don't think is a comedy but rather more like a drama love story I think and is some sort of slow. The part I'm interested in is when the man builds his house and along with it he creates a system of piping by using apparently some sort of bamboos cut in halves to carry water. About the language, you got a point. I don't remember but I'm pretty sure it was in English or perhaps in Spanish. The reason of this is because they don't talk much and I only remember the man working and fishing.

@DanielaDiaz You might want to imdb the movie "Bare Essentials"  It was made in 1991 and one of the men has a beard and has a romance with a woman.

@Daniela Diaz You could check out all the movies with "cast away" as a key word on imdb

Sounds like it was the 1986 film Castaway.
As the film starts, a man places a classified ad searching a "wife" for one year on an island. For legal reasons they have to marry before they go to the island.
On the island the man has a beard and does a lot fishing.
The film:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castaway_(film)
The book:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castaway_(book)

There is "Cast away" with Tom Hanks (not the one I'm referring to) and "Castaway" from 1986. IIRC all information from the question fits - what more can I say?

Very, very close. I think I'm going to watch it for fun. I added some details as a comment to clarify a bit more.

So it's probably another movie. Seems there are many cast away movies - and not surprising to see men with beards.

Sounds a bit like the 1998 romantic comedy Six Days Seven Night starring Harrison Ford and Anne Heche. The two main characters crash land on an abandoned island, and have trouble getting along at first. It's been a long time since I've seen the movie, but Harrison Ford plays a resourceful pilot so building a pulley system for water wouldn't be out of character.




Thank you for the answer. Seems like a nice movie to watch. I didn't know about it. The one I'm talking about is more quite and definitely the man has a beard.

It sounds a lot like 'Swept Away' I've linked the original here - but it was remade by Guy Ritchie in 2002 and starred Madonna. Sounds almost exactly as you describe - he hates her at the beginning but they become close... Linked here
